# How do I run grep multiple time parsing arguments from an input stream?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Imagine that input pipe is a list of words like `"foo", "bar"` in CSV format.

And then there's this file or something and I'd like to test whether it contains `"foo"` (1) or `"bar"` (2) so something like:

```
echo "foo\nbar" | grep input.txt $0
```

and I'd like to get merged result of these 2 grep operations in the output:

```
grep "foo" input.txt
grep "bar" input.txt
```

Example:

```
input.txt = "foo1\nfoo2n\bar\n123"
output = "foo1\nfoo2n\bar\n"
```

I don't care how many times it runs if it does search for all the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-f` flag that reads from a file, giving `/dev/stdin` as the filename, which makes it point to standard input.

```
printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" | grep -f /dev/stdin input.txt
```

Some implementations of Grep also allow for a hyphen `-` to represent standard input.

I have also used Printf (which prints "foo" and "bar" separated by newlines) because it is more portable than Echo. Bash Echo would require the `-e` flag to interpret `\n` as a newline character.

Comment: Thanks! Will it run grep 2 times separately for "foo" and "bar"? I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: You are welcome. Grep only runs once, but it matches lines with "foo" and lines with "bar". The difference to running 2 Greps, one for "foo" and other for "bar", is that there will be no duplicate lines. From your edit now, it seems that you want it to run twice?

Comment: Let's try to figure it out: What is your Grep? Can you show us `grep --version`? Does replace `-f -` by `-f /dev/stdin` work?